# clojure call function with result of itself in a loop

Tags: function, loops, parameters, clojure

Is there a clojure function that can be called in a loop with feeding it with the result of the previous call?

Pseudo-code might be look like this:

```
currentValue = firstValue;
while (endNotYetReached(currentValue)) {
  currentValue = myFunction(currentValue);
}
```

Thank you for every answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [iterate](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate), which returns an infinite lazy sequence, from which you can [take](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take), [drop](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/drop), etc:

```
=> (take 3 (iterate inc 5))
(5 6 7)
```

Comment: That's what I searched for. Thank you very much!